# Numpy 3D array max value

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[ 0.25,  0.10 ,  0.50 ,  0.15],
           [ 0.50,  0.60 ,  0.70 ,  0.30]],
          [[ 0.25,  0.50 ,  0.20 ,  0.70],
           [ 0.80,  0.10 ,  0.50 ,  0.15]]])
```

I need to find the row and column of the max value in a[i].
If i=0, a[0,1,2] is max, so I need to code a method that gives [1,2] as the output for max in a[0]. Any pointers, please?
NB: np.argmax flattens the a[i] 2D array and when axis=0 is used, it gives the index of max in each row of a[0]

Comment: I would suggest looking at numpy.argmax. This can be done by taking the index and then doing some quick math with the shape of the array.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `argmax` with `unravel_index`:

```
def max_by_index(idx, arr):
    return (idx,) + np.unravel_index(np.argmax(arr[idx]), arr.shape[1:])
```

e.g.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[ 0.25,  0.10 ,  0.50 ,  0.15],
               [ 0.50,  0.60 ,  0.70 ,  0.30]],
              [[ 0.25,  0.50 ,  0.20 ,  0.70],
               [ 0.80,  0.10 ,  0.50 ,  0.15]]])

def max_by_index(idx, arr):
    return (idx,) + np.unravel_index(np.argmax(arr[idx]), arr.shape[1:])


print(max_by_index(0, a))
```

gives

`(0, 1, 2)`

Comment: damn too late, was just about to post this. With the same mistake you corrected in the edit ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`numpy.where`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), which you can wrap in a simple function to meet your requirements:

```
def max_by_index(idx, arr):
    return np.where(arr[idx] == np.max(arr[idx]))
```

In action:

```
>>> max_by_index(0, a)
(array([1], dtype=int64), array([2], dtype=int64))
```

You can index your array with this result to access the maximum value:

```
>>> a[0][max_by_index(0, a)]
array([0.7])
```

This will return *all* locations of the maximum value, if you only want a single occurrence, you may replace **`np.max`** with  **`np.argmax`**.

Comment: Beware that `np.where` may not return anything at all when comparing float numbers with `==`

Answer (score 0):

```
col = (np.argmax(a[i])) % (a[i].shape[1])
row = (np.argmax(a[i])) // (a[i].shape[1])
```

This also helped